# sql server blocks after multiple failed connections from trusted ip

Tags: security, sql-server, ddos

We have a high load sql server that is not externally exposed.  The web server accesses the sql server over a lan.  For the most part it works great but from time to time when the sql server has multiple failed logins usually due to load if the server was restarted or just an extreme high load situation the sql server will begin to block the web server's ip.  We know this is the reason because we have a second lan ip specifically for this scenario.  We switch the ip and everything is fine.  The web server is iis.  When we simply restart IIS it doesn't fix it.

It puts us in a bind because the server needs the information from sql.  As more and more cache objects expire the server bombards sql until it gets what it wants.

We have found there to be failed audits for incorrect password but obviously the password is correct.  My guess is that something on the sql server is using the audits to block the web server but I don't know what.  I have looked for installed programs to no avail.

Comment: ` the sql server will begin to block the web server's ip. We know this is the reason because we have a second lan ip specifically for this scenario. We switch the ip and everything is fine`. That does not prove your conjecture.

Comment: This is techinally correct.  I guess we would have to try and make a connection outside of the app.  However, in each case we first restart the app without changing the ip.  It doesn't help.  Always changing the ip fixes it.  I am going to write a basic app for this test but it could be a long time before it happens again.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen slow performance on ASP .NET Web sites along with deadlocks and connectivity issues on the SQL Server side when using .NET Framework 4.5+. This is a bug that generates an inconsistency with the SessionState which implements the KeepSessionAliveHttpHandler via the IRequiresSessionState interface.

The bug was fixed on .NET Framework 4.5.1 but and reappeared on 4.7+. The community recommends to set the uploadReadAheadSize to unlimited. This seeting may create more consumption of RAM by IIS.

Please consider to [recycle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/?wt.mc_id=MVP) at least 2 times a day the application pool.

Comment: What about in the case of a sql server restart?  This is where it happens the most but as I said it can happen in extreme load conditions.  We have varnish so this is rare.

Comment: This was happening on a e-banking system and was happening during peak hours of usage 10 am to 5:00 am. many blockings/deadlocks where created and some users where unable to connect to the database. When we started to recycle the application pool with more frequency we started to handle it better. Install patches to the .NET Framework on the Web Server